# why isn't swfobject loading the flash div?

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I've edited this [page](http://www.radioperiferica.com) over ftp from a normal pc (without developer tools), which I can't install here.

Can anybody see why the swfobject isn't loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `swfobject` is not defined.

Comment: that was an swfobject script issue, i've changed the source to the google code API (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js) and it works, thanks for your help, much appreciated! +1 and Correct Answer

Comment: PS: that was another error on file: flashvar, i've to encode it via http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to put the url working.

I think that is a bug on SWF Object script, that doesn't encode the vars.

Comment: By the way, when I looke at your page again - i see that thecrossdomain.xml file is missing (http://87.117.196.121/crossdomain.xml)

Comment: The reason is flash is loading content (or sending/receiving variables) from another domain. You can read http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html there you can see also example for crossdomain file.